# Skipping records with particular value in mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I have a dataset with many records . 
Consider the first two fields of a record are field1 and field2.
If the value of field1 or field2 is AA , I have to skip this record in the mapping process.
Please help me with the program.

Answer (score 0):

In the mapper class you can put an if condition as

```
if((field1!='AA')||(field2!='AA')){

 //your code here
}
```

This if condition will skip the fields with value 'ÁA' and you will be able to process the rest of the records and you can return the outcomes to the context.

Comment: `||` should be `&&`, and it is better to compare strings using the String's `equals` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
map () {
  //your existing code to extract field1 and field2
  if (field1.equals("AA") || field2.equals("AA") {
    return; // map stops here. you can also increment a counter to count how many such records exist in your dataset
  }
  // add the rest of your existing code here
  context.write(...);
}
```